# Can you use Microsoft Power Automate to develop a company wide workflow solution?

Tags: power-automate

I am currently investigating possible tools with which to develop a workflow solution for a company that would be used by the staff to process incoming work and ensure incoming work is routed to the correct people for evaluation and are authorised by the relevant managers before work commences, and that the work is signed off when complete.

Is Microsoft Power Automate the right tool for this kind of work, or is it [simply] a tool for automating ones own personal tasks?  I'm looking for something that could be used to develop a tool that would be used by everyone in the company.

I've looked at the various videos but it looks like it might be just something for automating ones personal tasks rather than building something to be shared.  Is this correct or can it be used as a software development tool for developing a custom solution for a company?

Comment: any follow up questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at Business Process Flows (BPFs).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/business-process-flows-overview

The following text is from "[Why use business process flows?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/business-process-flow)" on the above link:

> Business process flows provide a guide for people to get work done.
> They provide a streamlined user experience that leads people through
> the processes their organization has defined for interactions that
> need to be advanced to a conclusion of some kind. This user experience
> can be tailored so that people with different security roles can have
> an experience that best suits the work they do.
>
> Use business process flows to define a set of steps for people to
> follow to take them to a desired outcome. These steps provide a visual
> indicator that tells people where they are in the business process.
> Business process flows reduce the need for training because new users
> don’t have to focus on which table they should be using. They can let
> the process guide them. You can configure business process flows to
> support common sales methodologies that can help your sales groups
> achieve better results. For service groups, business process flows can
> help new staff get up-to-speed more quickly and avoid mistakes that
> could result in unsatisfied customers.

You can create broad, or detailed, BPFs, to cover company wide business processes. You can also call on separate normal flows, validations, and more. There are a lot of ways you can use a BPF to move things forward in a company.

Answer (score 0):

Power Automate (aka MS Flow) is a low code/no code business workflow management or process orchestration software, getting more power with Robotic Process Automation & Virtual Agents inclusion.

The concept is having variety of connectors for all the available SaaS solutions (name anything like Dynamics, Salesforce, Oracle, SAP, Twitter, Facebook, Exchange mailbox, OneDrive, SharePoint, etc) to act as both Trigger and Action to achieve what we want. At worst case we can use REST APIs to complete the project setup.

Community demo the usefulness of it by showcasing the automation of personal stuffs but it has more. MS Flow is the alternate for Dynamics CRM 365 workflow and SharePoint workflow as well. Definitely it’s an enterprise candidate to solve company wide problems like onboarding, approvals, and many other workflow solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would look at Azure Logic Apps for that level. It has just about the same connectors as MS Flow , but with the addition of better management, troubleshooting and extensibility capabilities and you get all the benefits of security in Azure and compliance good stuff that companies would need

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Microsoft Power Automate can be used to develop a company-wide workflow solution, including user onboarding workflows. It allows you to automate business processes and integrate various Microsoft 365 services, such as SharePoint, Teams, and Outlook, to streamline and enhance productivity.
To learn more about developing a Microsoft 365 user onboarding workflow using Power Automate, you can refer to the blog post titled "**Microsoft 365 User Onboarding Workflow For Easy User Provisioning**"
In the blog post, you will likely find step-by-step instructions, tips, and best practices for creating a user onboarding workflow in Power Automate. It may cover topics such as setting up approval processes, sending notifications, and provisioning user accounts

> [Microsoft 365 User Onboarding Workflow For Easy User Provisioning](https://blog.admindroid.com/microsoft-365-user-onboarding-workflow-for-easy-user-provisioning/)